# Connecting to exchange server

Tags: php, exchange-server, pop3

I am trying to connect to my POP3 mail account on exchange server using a program written in PHP everytime i try to fsockopen and connect to mail box on port 110 i get connection time out error.

The username and pass of the account is correct.

Do i have to enable some connector on my exchange box to connect to third party applications ?

please help.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the POP3 connector is disabled. So, it should be enabled by your IT.

And ask them if they should also enable it for the account, I am not sure of this second part.

Comment: POP3 connector has been enabled. The problem is exchange server is refusing to take connection from the application. There might be a need for some receive connector to be enabled and allow the server IP to relay. Any idea on how to go about this ?

please help

Comment: There is no notion of relay for POP3 (only for SMTP).
How is authentication configured in the POP3 connector ? Maybe it does not accept username/password in clear text.